# How can we convert the dot product of 3 vectors to a matrix form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, self-learning, matrix-equations

How can we convert the dot product of 3 vectors to a matrix form?

In particular, 
We have $\sum_{i=1}^m (\langle \vec{w},\vec{x_i}\rangle -y_i)\vec{x_i} = 0$, how and why can we convert it to the following matrix form?

$Aw = b$
where 
$A = (\sum_{i=1}^m x_i x_i^T)$ and $b = \sum_{i=1}^{m} y_i \vec{x_i}$

Detailed derivation will be welcome! Thank you!

Comment: An attempted derivation on your part will also be welcome.

Comment: Thanks, I have got the correct answer by my effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, $\sum_{i=1}^m \langle \vec{w},\vec{x_i}\rangle \vec{x_i}$ can be referred to the following form:

$(\vec{x_1}, \vec{x_2},\dots, \vec{x_m})$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
\langle \vec{w},\vec{x_1}\rangle \\
\langle \vec{w},\vec{x_2}\rangle \\
\dots \\
\langle \vec{w},\vec{x_m}\rangle \\\end{array}\right]
$

Then $\left[\begin{array}{c}
\langle \vec{w},\vec{x_1}\rangle \\
\langle \vec{w},\vec{x_2}\rangle \\
\dots \\
\langle \vec{w},\vec{x_m}\rangle \\\end{array}\right]
$ can be reformulated as

$\left[\begin{array}{c}
\vec{x_1^T} \\
\vec{x_2^T} \\
\dots \\
\vec{x_m^T} \\\end{array}\right]
$$w$

Then we can get

$(\sum_{i=1}^m x_i x_i^T) w$